# Value of vector of structures changes unexpectedly

Tags: c++, structure, stdvector

I have a strange problem. There is a vector of structures. With a temporary structure, I push_back to that vector of structures. But when I check the first member's `cnt`, I see that it became changed. Any idea? (Below code is a simplified version but a representative one)

```
struct Vector
{
  float *dim;

  Vector ()
  {
    dim = new float [3];
  }
};

struct Face
{
  float an_N, an_P;
  int P, N;
  Vector Af;
  float Ad;
  Vector cnt;
  float ifac;
  float mf;
};

std::vector <Face> face;

Face temp_face;

for (;;)
{
    temp_face.cnt.dim[0] = 0.f;
    temp_face.cnt.dim[1] = 0.f;
    temp_face.cnt.dim[2] = 0.f;

    for (int q=0; q<n_vtx_2D; ++q)
    {
        temp_face.cnt = temp_face.cnt + pt[vtx[q]] / n_vtx_2D;                
    }                 

    face.push_back(temp_face);
}

std::cout << face[0].cnt.dim[0] << std::endl;
```

**Output**

0.25

0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default compiler generated copy constructor (and assignment operator) is being used for `Vector` and `Face` (but most importantly `Vector`). As the code re-uses the same instance of `Face`, named `temp_face`, all the instances of `Face` in the vector `face` point to the same `Face.cnt.dim` array (as the `faces` will contain copies of `temp_face`).

I can't see any reason for dynamically allocated the array inside `Vector` as it is a fixed size. Suggest changing to:

```
struct Vector
{
    float dim[3];
};
```

Or you need to implement copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor for `Vector`.
See [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for more information.

Comment: Everytime should I create a new `temp_face` in for-loop?

Comment: @Shibli, no. You need to fix `Vector`.

Comment: I fixed Vector as you said and it worked although I still have not understood the underlying problem. Thank you very much anyway!